# Rails: Fail to connect PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This is my database.yml:

```
production:
<<: *default
database: skilltracker_production
username: skilltracker
password: <%= ENV['SKILLTRACKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

When I run `bundle exec rake db:create:all`, I receive the following error message:
`fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

[...]

`Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"skilltracker_development", "host"=>"localhost"}
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "skilltracker"`

[...]

`Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"skilltracker_development", "username"=>"skilltracker", "password"=>"skilltracker"}`

[...]

`Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"skilltracker_production", "username"=>"skilltracker", "password"=>nil}`

Any ideal? Thanks for any help!

Comment: is the ENV['SKILLTRACKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] actually set? and can you confirm there is a user called "skilltracker"

Comment: ya. I have user skilltracker and passwork nil.

Comment: password nil? make sure your skilltracker user has a password for postgres and hard code that into your script. and report back

Comment: I change my skilltracker user's password to `14863456` and change my database.yml to:
`production:
 <<: *default
 database: skilltracker_production
 username: skilltracker
 password: '14863456'`
But I receive same error message.

Comment: just try to create the production db, not all and see if that works..just trying to narrow it down really

Comment: Can you teach me by  teamviewer my computer?

Comment: First can you try running this: RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create

Answer (score 0):

Sanity check: are you actually storing the password in that environment variable? Try hard coding it in that field as a troubleshooting step.

Comment: Tks. I will try to check